# How to make festival evaulate its own scheme expressions from the command line, so as to change voices as needed?

Tags: command-line, festival, text-to-speech

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

[This forum post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-41676.html) shows someone trying to change the voice used by festival, outside of the festival interpreter, using a command-line flag.

```
festival --\(voice_kal_diphone\) --tts "Langalist.txt"
```

It doesn't work. As a solution, the OP's program's configuration file ends up being edited. [Everyone](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=40548#) [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=3024c684c303c25437d8fd559408c364&t=751169) also seems to use that method to select voices. But surely, if from within the program's scheme interpreter the expression

```
luisetta@riverbrain:~$ festival

Festival Speech Synthesis System 2.1:release November 2010
Copyright (C) University of Edinburgh, 1996-2010. All rights reserved.

clunits: Copyright (C) University of Edinburgh and CMU 1997-2010
hts_engine: 
The HMM-based speech synthesis system (HTS)
hts_engine API version 1.04 (http://hts-engine.sourceforge.net/)
Copyright (C) 2001-2010  Nagoya Institute of Technology
              2001-2008  Tokyo Institute of Technology
All rights reserved.
For details type `(festival_warranty)'
festival> (voice_name_here)
```

from the list of voices returned by typing

```
festival> (voice.list)
```

works, then there must be a way to get the program to interpret its own scheme expressions via the command line too, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to select a voice before doing TTS, you can use `text2wave`

```
echo 'hello world' | text2wave -eval '(voice_kal_diphone)' > hello.wav
```

text2wave is a Festival script itself, so you could fairly easily customize it.

You can do similar with the Festival command line:

```
festival '(voice_ked_diphone)' '(SayText "hello world")' '(exit)'
```

but that unfortunately does not work along with the `--tts` option.

Comment: perfect! that eval switch is just what I needed. i knew there must be something like that. customizing text2wave is also a very good suggestion. the most logical first stop for festival hacking, actually.